# Separating emails from a common iTunes account

Tags: email

My wife and I share a common iTunes account. She bought a new iPad Air 2 and we used iTunes from my iPad to download her new iPad via iTunes. My e-mails come on her mail. How do I get her e-mails to come into her mail? We both use gmail.

Comment: What do you mean by "we used iTunes from my iPad to download her new iPad via iTunes"? And could you please clarify the whole issue with a few more details? The more the better, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've restored your iPad onto the new one of your wife. To change the email configuration on your wife's iPad

- go to **Settings** -> **Mail, Contacts, Calendar**
- delete your email account under Accounts (which will just remove it from the iPad and not actually delete it on Gmail's side)
- add your wife's Gmail account